# Comcast change IP address

Tags: ip

I have a question. I have Comcast Internet, a gateway. I want to change my external IP address because I was banned from Ebay (I returned some items and they really don't like that.. lol). Anyway, Comcast said the only way to change the IP address is to upgrade to their business account and purchase 5 static IP addresses. That is very expensive!

My question is: can I purchase a modem and attache it to the gateway to change my IP address? Some Internet forums say, yes this is possible, others say no. I just bought a NETGEAR Nighthawk AC1900 DualBand Router with DOCSIS 30 Cable Modem Black Model: C7000-100NAS. Will this modem help me change my IP address? I have tried VPN and TOR services but Ebay and PayPal ban those almost immediately.

I really need some help regarding this issue. Might you assist me? Thank you for your attention in this matter.

Comment: Don't do the crime if you can do the time. Ebay makes its rules, and you need to abide by those rules if you want to use its services.

Comment: eBay does not ban by IP address, it's not an effective method to ban users from a service like eBay, besides you already have a dynamic IP address more then likely since you don't have a static IP address.  eBay can easily ban you, as a person, only one of you.

Answer (score 1):

It won't help. *You* are banned. Changing your IP address won't change you. You will still be banned.

You do not have a technical problem.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: can I purchase a modem and [attach] it to the gateway to change my IP address?

Addresses are handed out by Comcast. There is no real way around this. What your betting on is that you can "trick" Comcast into an IP change via new hardware, which is a potentially expensive proposition with a (charitable) 50/50 chance it might work.

People often complain that their dynamic IPs change too often but with Comcast as my ISP, I can say my experience is different — I haven't had my "dynamic" IP change for almost 2 years through 3 hardware changes... so yeah. Hardware changes FTW! ;-)